# Boost unit test multi-threaded tests

Tags: c++, multithreading, unit-testing, boost

I am using Boost.Test for unit tests and want to unit test some things that will require multiple threads. I could simply create whatever threads I need in the test case, but am looking for a way that is fairly resilient to test failures, and wont just leave the test case deadlocked.

e.g. something like a `BOOST_TEST_NEW_THREAD(main_func)` that will let the created thread use `BOOST_CHECK_*` etc. with correct logging,  log unexpected exceptions, etc.

This is for both Windows and Linux.